# Portions of SVG that were offscreen while zoomed in disappear when zooming back out

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions

I'm using css transitions to animate zooming into an SVG. The only problem is that when zooming out, portions of the SVG are missing until the animation is complete and then it all pops in.

*(Only tested in Chrome on a Mac so far)*

[image: svg zoom out pop in]

I'm not changing the SVG at all, just zooming in and then back out by setting the a `scale` `transform` on a group in the SVG.

How can I make the browser re-render these offscreen elements so that don't pop in like this?

```js
const root = document.getElementById('root')

setTimeout(function() {
  root.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(10,10)')
}, 1)

setTimeout(function() {
  root.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(1,1)')
}, 4200)
```

```css
#root {
  transition: 4s transform;
}

circle {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 300 100">
  <g id="root">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
    <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="50" />
    <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="50" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="50" />
    <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="50" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but I think Chrome creates a raster image when using transitions. Then, when the transition is complete, updates the DOM. It's a performance thing. Not sure how to fix, but maybe knowing that will get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, this is probably because of some optimizations in the CSS renderer.
This is a Chrome bug <sub>(one of the many they have with their CSS paintings optimizations...)</sub>, and you should [let them know about it](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).

For the time being, have you considered using SMIL instead?

Since you used javascript in your code, I will assume you run this in a browser from some place where script execution is allowed (i/e not in `<img>` tag), and hence where you will be able to use a polyfill like [FakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/).
So this will actually offer you a better browser support than through CSS transitions (IIRC IE<11 didn't support CSS transform transitions on svg elements), and moreover than the still experimental SVG2 only mix-up *CSS transition of SVGTransformAttribute*. 
Indeed, only Chrome does *support* it for now (probably because while some attributes were already CSS transitionable in SVG1.1, `transform` having a different syntax than its CSS equivalent, the algo should be differents).

Here is what your example would look like in SMIL:

```js
// and if you need JS control
document.onclick = e => {
  document.getElementById('zoomin').beginElement();
};
```

```css
circle {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  transform: translateZ(1);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 300 100">
  <g id="root">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" id="zoomin"
      from="1 1" to="10 10" dur="4s" begin="1s"/>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" id="zoomout"
      from="10 10" to="1 1" dur="4s" begin="zoomin.end"/>    
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
    <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="50" />
    <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="50" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="50" />
    <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="50" />
  </g>
  <!-- for IE -->
  <script xlink:href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/FakeSmile/FakeSmile/master/smil.user.js"></script>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about, transition every circle,
is this ok for you?

I actually dont have an explanation about why it works this way

```js
const circles = document.getElementsByTagName('circle')

setTimeout(function() {
  circles[0].setAttribute('transform', 'scale(10,10)');
  circles[1].setAttribute('transform', 'scale(10,10)');
  circles[2].setAttribute('transform', 'scale(10,10)');
  circles[3].setAttribute('transform', 'scale(10,10)');
  circles[4].setAttribute('transform', 'scale(10,10)');
}, 1)

setTimeout(function() {
   circles[0].setAttribute('transform', 'scale(1,1)');
   circles[1].setAttribute('transform', 'scale(1,1)');
   circles[2].setAttribute('transform', 'scale(1,1)');
   circles[3].setAttribute('transform', 'scale(1,1)');
   circles[4].setAttribute('transform', 'scale(1,1)');
}, 4200)
```

```css
#root {
  transition: 4s transform;
}

circle {
 stroke: white;
 stroke-width: 3px;
 transition: 4s transform;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 300 100">
 <g id="root">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
   <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="50" />
   <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="50" />
   <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="50" />
   <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="50" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Huh, that's interesting. I bet this will perform a lot worse with a lot of elements, but it does seem to get the job done without visual artifacts.

Comment: Hmm, also, this does not seem to work when applied to groups, and my real problem is a much bigger SVG where it's not practical to apply this transform to every single renderable element.  There will be thousands.

Answer (score 1):

Why not transition the entire `svg` element?

```js
const root = document.getElementById('root')

setTimeout(function() {
  root.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(10,10)')
}, 1)

setTimeout(function() {
  root.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(1,1)')
}, 4200)
```

```css
#root {
  transition: 4s transform;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

circle {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="root" viewbox="0 0 300 100">
  <g>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
    <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="50" />
    <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="50" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="50" />
    <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="50" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This does solve the problem in my contrived example, but I need to be able to zoom into specific areas. And if I do it this way, translations are then in the coordinate space of the page, not the SVG, which makes it really hard to to figure out how to translate things around properly.

Answer (score 0):

The `setAttribute` need the `style` attribue. Try this script:

```
setTimeout(function() {
 root.setAttribute('style', 'transform: scale(10,10)')
}, 1)

setTimeout(function() { 
    root.setAttribute('style', 'transform: scale(1,1)')
}, 4200)
```

Comment: Sadly, this has the same problem.